# Must specify package names on the command line

Tags: macos, makefile

I'm trying to compile gdis on osx el capitan.

[Downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdis) the gdis version available from developer, but once i click the executable of the release version, nothing happens.

So, i've followed the [developer instructions](http://gdis.sourceforge.net/download.html), compiling CVS and Perl (from homebrew), to get the development version, executing this from terminal:

> Blockquote

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@gdis.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gdis login
```

Hit enter at the password prompt, then type:

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@gdis.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gdis co gdis
```

which should create a folder called gdis containing all the source files.

Enter the gdis subdirectory and run the install script, which should automatically compile gdis based on your preferences.

It should also inform you of missing libraries that must be installed.

> Blockquote

running the install script, which is inside Macintosh HD/Users/nBogoni/gdis, it renders the following message:

```
Checking pre-requisite packages.
gtk+-2.0              [ok]
gtkglext-1.0          [ok]
Compiling [gdis] ... [failed] check install.log
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Checking the install.log file, it says:

```
Must specify package names on the command line
makefile:4: makefile.osx: No such file or directory
makefile:5: makefile.src: No such file or directory
makefile:18: makefile.other: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `makefile.other'.  Stop.
```

This is what I have inside the makefile.osx, inside Macintosh HD/Users/nBogoni/gdis

```
    # --- gdis Makefile for OS-X

    CC = gcc
    #CFLAGS = -O2 -no-cpp-precomp
    CFLAGS = -O2 

    INCS := $(INCS) -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers
    LIBS := $(LIBS) -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries
```

inside the  makefile.src on gdis folder, inside Macintosh HD/Users/nBogoni/gdis

```
# --- gdis Makefile sources

SRC =   main.c model.c coords.c connect.c matrix.c task.c \
type.c measure.c parse.c edit.c elem.c select.c surface.c \
analysis.c spatial.c render.c numeric.c project.c grid.c \
molsurf.c hirshfeld.c zone.c contents.c quaternion.c zmatrix.c \
library.c geometry.c space.c sginfo.c sgclib.c sgio.c error.c \
scan.c camera.c defect.c colourlib.c mdi.c \
mesch.c mesch_core.c host.c command.c undo.c count.c \
ff.c ff_gulp.c scalar.c animate.c test.c \
file.c file_cif.c file_gulp.c file_gmf.c file_marvin.c file_xtl.c \
file_arc.c file_xyz.c file_siesta.c file_gms.c file_diff.c file_xml.c \
file_abinit.c file_pdb.c file_povray.c file_nwchem.c file_castep.c \
file_gauss.c file_rietica.c file_geomview.c file_cssr.c file_cel.c \
file_dmol.c file_dlpoly.c file_bgf.c file_cgf.c file_dlp.c \
file_gromacs.c file_meta.c file_aims.c file_gauss_cube.c \
file_pwscf.c file_xsf.c file_openmx.c file_reaxmd.c \
import.c graph.c grisu_client.c 

ifeq ($(USE_GUI), YES)
SRC := $(SRC) gui_main.c gui_canvas.c gui_shorts.c \
gl_main.c gl_primitives.c gl_stereo.c gl_graph.c gl_varray.c \
gui_gulp.c gui_siesta.c gui_render.c gui_mdi.c gui_animate.c \
gui_edit.c gui_surface.c gui_analysis.c gui_defect.c gui_nwchem.c \
gui_molsurf.c gui_diffract.c gui_gms.c gui_library.c gui_setup.c \
gui_gperiodic.c gui_space.c gui_measure.c gui_symmetry.c gui_zmatrix.c \
gui_dialog.c gui_tree.c gui_task.c gui_help.c gui_job.c \
    dock.c image.c gui_grid.c gui_project.c
endif

ifeq ($(USE_GRISU), YES)
SRC := $(SRC) stdsoap2.c soapC.c soapClient.c logging.c grid_certificates.c \
py_login.c
#   jni_grisu.c
endif
```

and the makefile.other, also inside Macintosh HD/Users/nBogoni/gdis

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    /bin/rm -f $(OBJ) gdis
    /bin/rm -fr gdis.app
    /bin/rm -f gdis.dmg

.PHONY: tgz
tgz:
    tar -czvf gdis-source.tgz \
    install makefile makefile.* \
    README CHANGELOG TODO GPL.txt gdis.manual gdis.elements gdis.library \
    *.c *.h *.xpm grisu.wsdl grisu*.nsmap;

.PHONY: zip
zip:
    zip gdis-source.zip \
    install makefile makefile.* \
    README CHANGELOG TODO GPL.txt gdis.manual gdis.elements gdis.library \
    *.c *.h *.xpm grisu.wsdl grisu*.nsmap;

.PHONY: binzip
binzip:
    zip -r gdis-bin.zip \
    gdis gdis.elements gdis.library gdis.manual lib/init.jar lib/sggc.jar
```

Could someone help me solving this, since I'm new to mac terminal.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: a little more of context please

Comment: Checking the install.log file, i guess i have to write the file directories inside them, but i don't know how to do that. What you mean by context?

Comment: tried to bring more information into the topic. Sorry, I'm new to terminal and to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Well, to this problem, the solution I found was to run the following command inside the installation directory.

```
./install all
```

Than with that, the install file could locate the makefiles.

Thanks anyway, even if no one got interested in helping me.